# python winreg unable to write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.9, winreg

When using the following code block, I cannot write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is fine. There are no errors reported when attempting to write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. There is no endpoint protection installed that would restrict writing to the registry.

Using python 3.9.1 and psutil 5.8.0 on Windows 10 64-bit and script is being executed as administrator.

```
import winreg
#HKEY_CURRENT_USER
with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as root:
    with winreg.CreateKeyEx(root, 'Software\AAA', 0, access = winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY | winreg.KEY_WRITE) as key:
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, "PATH", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, 'test')

# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as root:
    with winreg.CreateKeyEx(root, 'Software\AAA', 0, access = winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY | winreg.KEY_WRITE) as key:
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, "PATH", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, 'test')
```

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rghC.png)

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0DDs.png)

```
C:\Users\admin\source\repos> python3 test.py

C:\Users\admin\source\repos>
```

Anyone have an idea of what I'm missing?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to python 3.8.7 and at first onset seems to be working.